Translate CVSection in AwesomeCV fails with extra '}'
I am migrating my previous CV from Twenty Seconds to Awesome CV but I am having a hard time translating some parts of the document.
I use the translator package and everything works as expected within section bodies (e.g. cvskills) but I cannot figure out how to translate sections.
Here's the main tex file:
\providecommand{\getlang}{french}
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, \getlang]{awesome-cv}

% packages declaration
\usepackage[\getlang]{babel}
\usepackage{translator}

% document configuration
\usedictionary{curriculum}
\geometry{left=1.4cm, top=.8cm, right=1.4cm, bottom=1.8cm, footskip=.5cm}
\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-emerald}
\setbool{acvSectionColorHighlight}{true}

% render document
\begin{document}
  \makecvheader
  \makecvfooter
    {\today}
    {}
    {\thepage}


  \input{parts/introduction}
\end{document}

and here's the content of parts/introduction.tex:
\cvsection{\translate{category-intro}} % this part crashes, but works if I remove the call to \translate

\begin{cvparagraph}
    \translate{cv-intro} % this part always works, I get the translated text
\end{cvparagraph}

The translations are defined in two dictionaries, here's an example of how they are used:
\ProvidesDictionary{curriculum}{French}

\deftranslation{category-intro}{Introduction}
\deftranslation{cv-intro}{
  blahblah
}

The error I get when I try to translate the \cvsection part is always the same:

(./parts/introduction.tex
! Argument of \@sectioncolor has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.3 \cvsection{\translate{category-intro}}
                                          
? 
! Emergency stop.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.3 \cvsection{\translate{category-intro}}

The sources for the AwesomeCV are available here and I use the latest version (master) of it.
